# How to use foreign keys in Ruby on the Rails query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have three models; **events**, **users** and **entries**. I would like on my users page for to be able to retrieve information relating to the events associated with the event associated with the user.

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @entry = @user.entries.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

It is more than happy with `@user.entries.count` but I would like to link up in a table something like this:

Event Name - Event Location - Course

My models are bellow:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy

class Entry < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :event
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're related as:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :entries
  belongs_to :user
end

class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Then you can use joins starting from Entry, up to User and check events where the user id is the one what you need:

```
Entry.joins(event: :user).where(users: { id: user_id })
```

Comment: I get this error on rails console. `'NameError: undefined local variable or method user_id for main:Object' ?`

Comment: `user_id` is a placeholder value I added as example, you need to use a numeric value corresponding to any user id that you know exists in your database @Tom :).

Comment: I tried - `entry = Entry.joins(event: :user).where(users: { id: 2 })` I still get nowhere. Apparently, 'ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Event' to association named 'user'; perhaps you misspelled it?' . What should 'user' refer to?

Comment: Okay, I'm looking at your models now.

Comment: For your models, does this work `Entry.joins(:event, :user).where(users: { id: 1 })`?

Comment: The SQL executes but I get `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []> ` as a result

Comment: So you don't have related records that satisfy that query, try creating a few ones, let me know if that works. Also, just to know, mustn't Event be related to a User?, just wondering.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that I had deleted the user with ID 1. Although this doesn't fit stack exchange policy, I appreciate the time you spent on this. :)

Comment: Always glad to help Tom ;), just remember for the next time to not to use playable snippets if your code isn't playable.